# Is it possible to split database tables using HyperDB?

Tags: database, mysql, hyperdb

I'm looking for an answer from someone who's implemented HyperDB or has knowledge of it.

I have a database which has just passed the 100mb mark a week or so ago, the problem is my host only allows databases of 100mb a time. I was looking to implement HyperDB but wanted to find out some information first.

My current database is around 100mb alone on the posts table of the database. If I implement HyperDB will this table get split between two databases?

Comment: It also sounds like it's about time you upgraded to a better host.  If they're limiting the size of your db, you're probably still using shared hosting.  If your site's large enough and popular enough, you should *really* consider looking in to a VPS or dedicated server.

Comment: It's something I'm looking in to at the moment actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HyperDB lets you split whole tables across different databases but it won't split a single table. You wouldn't want that anyway because that means wordpress would have to query multiple databases to find a single post.

However, depending on how your site is set up, you might be able to work around that by creating a multisite wordpress install using subdirectories. That means splitting your site up into subdirectories that are actually separate wordpress installs. Then you can use hyperdb to distribute those tables.

Or an easier thing to do is find a web host that doesn't limit your database size :)

Comment: Looking in to a new host at the moment! :)